# Stamped Chinese characters on a banknote

Tags: translation, traditional-characters, character-identification

[image]

I cannot translate, it would be great if you guys could. It's a stamp on a Hong Kong banknote from 1941.

Answer (score 7):

Read right to left, top to bottom.

> 富行揀選
>
> 樣券

富行 was short for 雲南富滇銀行 (The Yunnan "Fu-Tien" Bank), 揀選 meant "select, pick".

樣券 means "banknote sample".

[image: Sample]

PS: Welcome to Chinese.SE. However, this kind of question is off-topic. Because

> Questions asking for translations are off-topic unless prior research effort is clearly indicated; we're here to help you learn, not provide a bulk translation service.

Comment: Why then did you answer this off-topic question?

Comment: @monalisa my opinion on how to deal with a newcomer's off-topic questions is "to answer or not to answer is an alternative, but just vote to close." Because anyway few newcomers would read the regulations before asking a question (that is to say, closing a question doesn't teach any new-newcomer a lesson), I think answering it won't cause a flood of off-topic questions.

Comment: FWIW closed questions with answers that are upvoted / accepted [don't](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/261498) go through the automatic deletion process. So to some degree, answering them might increase the number of low-quality, off-topic questions that stay on the site...

Comment: @Stan If few newcomers would read the regulations before asking a question, then it is even more important for those who know the regulations not to encourage any question that contradicts them. Answering off-topic questions sends a clear message that such question will, in fact, be answered even though they are against SE policy. I don't follow your logic in saying answering it won't cause a flood of off-topic questions. We are already experiencing a fair number of "request for translation" type questions. I am sure they will keep coming as long as someone answers them.

Comment: As an aside, if this is a bill from the 雲南富滇銀行, this cannot be a HK bill, as the OP said, right?

Comment: @monalisa IMO, it depends. Yes, this question is asking for translation and doesn't show any efforts, but recognising such kind of characters is not easy. And Stan gave a wonderful answer, which make it possible to benefit future users. IMO, it should be fine.

Comment: @Maroon Thanks for the information. To keep this website "cleaner", I think high-rep users should check the "review -> Tools" more frequently to cast delete votes. But, actually, I think the "unless prior research effort is clearly indicated" point is a little vague and questions like this one are not asking for "**bulk** translation".

Comment: @monalisa By *newcomer* I meant "those who ask their first question". Of course, a second off-topic question from a not-so-new-comer should be suppressed. The logic is, if a *newcomer* doesn't read the regulations, and there's a ratio of newcomers posting "request for translation" type questions, then the appearance of that kind of questions (more or less) only depends on the total amount of *newcomers* multiplying the ratio (provided most *newcomers* don't know each other). Anyway I don't have statistical data so that's only conjecture.

Comment: @monalisa And I agree we should not encourage the off-topic, but for *newcomers*, a blunt shut-down would make them feel us kind of, condescending – that's not a good way to welcome newcomers. So, for this question that is not asking for **bulk** translation, I don't think it that bad.

Comment: @dda I don't know. Maybe it could circulate in HK back then.

Comment: Well, if any part of the regulations is not clear, then perhaps there should be a channel for us to lobby and get it clarified. As it stands, it is just open for interpretation. All I am trying to do is to uphold the policy of the SE community regarding prior research effort. Also, shutting down a question need not be condescending. It can definitely be done nicely and civilly.

Comment: @monalisa: if anything, I've gotten the impression that the site meta is usually the place to raise such questions. In any case I'd agree that shutting down a question need not be something dismissive.